# Using rsync to backup

Tags: backup, macos, rsync

I currently back up the contents of an external hard drive A by (1) deleting everything in the destination external hard drive B and (2) copying everything from A to B (in Finder). The external hard drive only contains “basic data” (folders, images, videos, documents, etc.), nothing fancy/weird.

But with all the amazing free tools that exist out there I couldn't find a decent one to backup (suggestions accepted).

I want to automize this. After a few searches, it seems I can use `rsync`. I want then to automize this by using `rsync` to avoid copying files that are already on the destination hard drive (of course, if a change has been made, I want to update the file/folder; the same with deleted files/folders or new files/folders; the idea is to mimic what I usually do manually with Finder).

I got to this point

```
rsync -av --progress --delete /Volumes/A/ /Volumes/B
```

Now the log is full of files which name starts with `.` or `._` or even `._.`. Are they necessary?

### Question

How can I copy only the files that matter, leaving all those that don't matter behind. For example, if I have `photo.png` I would expect to copy `photo.png`, not `._photo.png` or many files.

What `--exclude` or `--exclude-from` can be used safely on a Mac? May be a good rule is “just copy anything that Finder shows” which is what I would copy if I passed manually through all folders.

### Extra question

Is `-av --progress --delete` enough? Am I committing a crime or risking some data? What options would you use.

*Please, back your answer with some arguments, I would appreciate it.*

I'm looking for a way to automate `rsync` which seems quite powerful and free to use.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35077/discussion-on-question-by-manuel-using-rsync-to-backup).

Comment: On the strategy described on the 1st paragraph, what happens if after (1) – deleting everything in B – a serious issue happens to A? You could lose access to data on A and on its previous backup. If your backup storage has enough space, how about deleting the backup only after a newer backup was completed successfully?

Comment: @bmike's link to the conversation that was moved to chat is broken.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## For Maximum Safety, Copy Everything

The *safest* option is to *copy everything*, including invisible meta-data files.

Files tend to exist for a reason and as software changes, so will the existence, purpose, and contents of these meta-data files. Copying everything will reduce the maintenance burden and offer ease of mind that nothing is being lost.

The log file created by `rsync` will be technically involved by the very nature of `rsync` being a command line tool. Consider presenting a tidied up, meta-data filtered, and maybe even coloured coded output for the user to check. You could do this with a wide range of scripting tools and languages. Please ask more questions here on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) and on [StackOverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com) if you need help with this approach.

### Delete Last & Copy OS X Resources

Regarding the `rsync` flags, take a look at the question [Fastest and safest way to copy massive data from one external drive to another](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117465/fastest-and-safest-way-to-copy-massive-data-from-one-external-drive-to-another/117469#117469). In this question, a few additional flags are used and explained:

```
sudo rsync -vaE --progress --delete-after /Volumes/SourceName /Volumes/DestinationName
```

In this situation, the `E` will ensure resource forks and other Mac specific properties are copied.

You may want to consider `--delete-after` to avoid deleting until the copy has completed; please note that this approach will potentially require a destination drive twice the size of the source.

## Possible Exclusions

An answer to a related question, [How can I omit FCPX Render Files from a Time Machine backup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85778/how-can-i-omit-fcpx-render-files-from-a-time-machine-backup), provided a useful link of [OS X files and folders that can be excluded from most back-ups](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc4/some-files-and-folders-are-automatically-excluded-from-backup-task). This link provides a practical list of file patterns, folders, and paths that you could exclude.

### Include dot Files

There are good reasons to back up files beginning with dots, `.*` matching files.

Some software keeps preferences, settings, and other information of value in folders at the top of the user's folder in invisible dot prefixed folders. Running `ls -la ~/` will reveal these folders and files.

If any user uses or has software that in turn uses version control software, be sure to back-up dot files. Software like [subversion](https://subversion.apache.org) and [git](http://www.git-scm.com) both store critical information within their dot folders. These hidden folders can be scattered across your file system, where ever a project is checked out.

## Spotlight and Disk Access

Spotlight is OS X's search service. Spotlight uses the `mdworker` process to index and update the search catalogue. If you are concerned about possible disk corruption or slow copies, [disabling `mdworker`](http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/14/mdworker-what-is-mdworker/) while running `rsync` may help. Personally, I leave Spotlight running while running large `rsync` transfers.

Comment: *The safest option is to copy everything, including invisible meta-data files.* But that same link from Carbon Copy Cloner says that there are certain files that are automatically built so it may even corrupt them if you copied with `rsync`.

Comment: Some files will be recreated but is the effort required in isolating those files and tracking changes in behaviour across multiple versions of software worth the time and risk? Maybe, but for most situations copy everything and keep those back-ups safe. The CCC exclusion list is reasonable and, if desired, can be encoded in an exclusion file for `rsync` to use.

Comment: You could add a full example for future readers. I found two sources, [one](https://gist.github.com/tvwerkhoven/4541989) and [two](http://alanwsmith.com/rsync-exclude-list-for-mac-osx) (plus the [third one](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc4/some-files-and-folders-are-automatically-excluded-from-backup-task) that you linked); I leave them here for future reference.

Comment: "There are good reasons to back up files beginning with dots": **yes!** These files are hidden (from the Finder for the dummies) but most of the time these are very important files.

Comment: The `E` and `--delete-after` are the key points which make of this answer a winning one.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Those are the nitpickings I wanted to see in an answer: what things should I take care in Mac OS X? In my particular case, as I stated, I only have photos, videos or documents, there's no “magic” programs as in `~/`. In my case I thinks I'm pretty safe with `--ignore ' .*'` since it would be the same exact thing as if I downloaded a photo from the internet (I don't download aux files, those are *generated* from the computer). Now I wanted arguments that said: “yes you can imagine you download from the internet a photo, but it would be much if you did X”.

Comment: @danielAzuelos As of `-E`, in newer versions there's `-X` which I see recommended in some places, which one si the correct? Or both of them? I would like an up to date, pseudo-complete that covers most of the general worries. Would copying Spotlight files be easier and faster than letting them be generated? How can I stop Spotlight so it doesn't mess meanwhile? What about `caffeinate`ing the process? Or may be if it's just a backup list make it not indexable by Spotlight, much less worries, etc. Many of this questions have been answered for sure.

Comment: @Manuel on Ask Different, we prefer to limit questions to one concise query. Please can you [ask new questions](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for these additional enquiries and refinements.

Comment: @GrahamMiln My question is “what to take in account when specifically trying to use `rsync` on Mac OS X”, all of those are just ideas that one might answer.

Comment: Manuel is correct to point this out; check your rsync version with "rsync --version" if you're using the stock version at /usr/bin/rsync, it is version 2.x as of 2018 and you use the "-E" flag. If you're using a newer 3.x version, like one from homebrew, "-X" is the extended attribute flag.

Comment: When I try to use `-E` to sync to a drive on my Raspberry Pi, I get the error, `rsync: on remote machine: --extended-attributes: unknown option`. I assume this means that I can only use `-E` locally (or at least if I have macOS for source and destination)?

Comment: @Merchako this would make [a good new question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: So far, there are two questions in this comment thread that I think are highly relevant to establishing a good answer to *this* question. I believe the follow-up questions should be included because (1) they're highly depended on this question, and (2) they would help determine what makes a good answer. In contrast, @GrahamMiln has recommended both of them be separate questions. Can we get a reference or an opinion from a third party to establish what the right approach would be?

Comment: @Merchako Ask Different encourages one question at a time as this promotes focused answers. Let's discuss your format concerns with the moderators and other interested users on https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3590/how-to-address-follow-on-questions

Answer (score 7):

I'm not completely pleased with the current answers, but I will try to cover here a bit of the possibilities that I've seen on the web trying to find a nice setup for `rsync`.

And, by the way, if one is interested in Time Machine like copies, there's [`rsnapshot`](http://rsnapshot.org). And there's also [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) for two way syncronizations. Plus, there's actually a few GUIs, like [Backup Utility](https://www.davidwaring.net/projects/backup.html) and [arRsync](http://arrsync.sourceforge.net); not exactly what I was looking for but they might do the job for somebody.

First, my only intention was to duplicate photos and videos, so exact copy wasn't needed, hence no need to care *too much*. In fact most of my doubts were if I could exclude everything (the same that would happen if, say, I downloaded a photo from the internet, I just download a .png, everything else is not downloaded *but autogenerated*).

Here's an unstructured list of thoughts that you may want to take in account

- I you want to ensure that your laptop doesn't go to sleep, you may want to `caffeinate` the process `caffeinate -s rsync -av ...`. Taken from [here](http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/mac_rsync.html).
- If you are doing local copies, like in my case, or even if internet connection is not too slow, you should *not* use `-z` option (compression), and use `-W` (transfer whole file, rather than delta transfers; this is a default when local) and probably use `--inplace` to make transfers fast. Taken from [here](https://superuser.com/q/109780/172607).
- You can use `--delete-after` so any file will be first transferred, and then moved on destination (and deleted the original one) and is safer than deleting before the transfer or during the transfer.
- You can stop the transfer by pressing <kbd>ctrl + C</kbd>, and it will stop cleanly. Taken from [here](https://superuser.com/q/1032692/172607). This was one of my fears with SuperDuper!, if you need to stop a transfer you get the message “You will leave the hard drive in an unknown state…”.
- In recent versions there's `--info=progress2` which adds even more details to `-v`.
- There's `-P` (which equals `--partial` and `--progress`) that will leave mid-transferred files there so you can keep going when you restart the process (if for some reason you can't end the syncronization at once).
- One might be interested in stopping Spotlight or TimeMachine before doing the copy, and reenable them after the transfer. And even disable Spotlight for the external disk.
- Other options used in all those references include `-x` (or `--one-file-system`), `-E` (`--executability`), `-H` (`--hard-links`), `-X` (`--xattrs`), `-A` (`--acls`), and `--sparse`, `--hfs-compression`, `--protect-decmpfs`. You may want to look at them.

For me, a basic command looks like (I might use more options, but this is enough for an example):

```
caffeinate -s rsync -av --delete-after --progress --stats --exclude-from 'excludefile.txt' \
  "/Volumes/SrcHDD/" "/Volumes/DstHDD" # note the trailing slash / after the source
```

Now in my case I could just include `{*.jpg,*.png,*.mp4,*.txt,*.pdf,…}` and no one would say “you need also system files” but since I don't want to search to get all the possible filetype I have files of, I prefer to exclude. And there are things that not only can be but *seem convenient* to exclude.

I found a few links, take what you want:

1. https://bombich.com/kb/ccc4/some-files-and-folders-are-automatically-excluded-from-backup-task
2. https://gist.github.com/tvwerkhoven/4541989
3. https://github.com/necolas/dotfiles
4. https://gist.github.com/shkm/5531679
5. http://www.hackurmac.com/2014/08/backing-up-and-restoring-your-hackintosh.html
6. https://github.com/jedda/Counterpart
7. http://alanwsmith.com/rsync-exclude-list-for-mac-osx

And from there you could probably get what's safe or sane to ignore. Here's the full list (I just removed duplicates)

```
.HFS+ Private Directory Data*
/.journal
/.journal_info_block
.AppleDouble
.AppleDB
/lost+found

.metadata_never_index
.metadata_never_index_unless_rootfs
/.com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent
.VolumeIcon.icns
/System/Library/CoreServices/.disk_label*
/TheVolumeSettingsFolder

.DocumentRevisions-V100*
.Spotlight-V100
/.fseventsd
/.hotfiles.btree
/private/var/db/systemstats

/private/var/db/dyld/dyld_*
/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.bootstamps/*
/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.corestorage/*
/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kext.caches/*

/.com.apple.NetBootX

/Volumes/*
/dev/*
/automount/*
/Network/*
/.vol/*
/net

/private/var/folders/zz/*
/private/var/vm/*
/private/tmp/*
/cores/*

.Trash
.Trashes

/Backups.backupdb
/.MobileBackups
/.MobileBackups.trash
/.MobileBackups.trash

Library/Mobile Documents.*
.webtmp

/Library/Caches/CrashPlan
/PGPWDE01
/PGPWDE02
/.bzvol
/Library/Application Support/Comodo/AntiVirus/Quarantine
/private/var/spool/qmaster
$Recycle.Bin
Saved Application State
Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.loginwindow*

.AppleDesktop
.com.apple.timemachine.supported
Network Trash Folder
/Library/Caches/*
/private/var/spool/postfix/*
$RECYCLE.BIN
/stuff/*
/afs/*
/private/var/run/*
/Previous Systems.localized
/tmp/*
.dbfseventsd
.DS_Store
.PKInstallSandboxManager
.SymAV*
.symSchedScanLockxz
.TemporaryItems
Desktop DB
Desktop DF
hiberfil.sys
pagefile.sys
Recycled
RECYCLER
System Volume Information
Temporary Items
Thumbs.db
AUTORUN.INF
Autorun.inf
autorun.inf
```

Answer (score 6):

### It's August, 2022; This is an updated answer:

Before getting into the answer here, you must know that although an `rsync` binary is included with macOS, it is now an ancient, 16-year-old software package. On my Catalina system `/usr/bin/rsync --version` reports itself as ver 2.6.9; released in Nov, 2006. The [`rsync` release history](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/NEWS#3.0.0) since ver 2.6.9 seems to make it clear that Apple's decision to halt upgrades for `rsync` on their OS was based entirely upon the `rsync` team's decision to switch to the GPLv3 license. This is unfortunate because `rsync` ver 3.0 (the release following 2.6.9) included significant upgrades specifically supporting macOS users:

- `--xattrs` : preserves OS X extended attributes
- `--acls` : preserves OS X Access Control Lists
- `--fake-super` : allows non-admin users to preserve all attributes

The *point* of the above paragraph is simply this: ***If you want to use `rsync` to back up files on your macOS, you must have a later version than the one Apple provides.***  Otherwise, you will lose all `xattrs` and `ACLs` - metadata that plays a significant role in several features of macOS. [This is easily verified with a simple experiment.](https://github.com/seamusdemora/seamusdemora.github.io/blob/master/RsyncWithNoMetaDataLoss.md)

Fortunately, current versions of `rsync` are available from 3rd party macOS package managers ([MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) for example), or for the DIY-inclined, you can clone the [`rsync` GitHub repo](https://github.com/WayneD/rsync) and build it from source.

It's also worth noting that a current version of `rsync` can repair/restore a backup made previously using Apple's *native* `rsync` ver 2.6.9. [It can also repair/restore `xattrs`, `ACL`s and date-timestamps that have been  mangled or lost by Apple's "Migration Assistant".](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/444386/149366)

`rsync` is a mature & *comprehensive* package with numerous options. Many of these options are not obvious choices, and one can spend a fair amount of time developing an *option set* to meet specific objectives. While there are no real shortcuts to careful consideration of your own use-case, I'll suggest the following *option sets* as a reasonable *generic* `rsync` command for general use on macOS - a *"point of departure"* in other words. You may further tailor these to meet your own needs.

I'll present two cases for using `rsync` to backup and restore; one using the `--delete` option, and one without. Both cases assume the local `Macintosh HD` is the source for the backup operation, and the destination for the restore operation. In my own case, there are some folders (e.g. `Documents`) for which I prefer to use the `--delete` option, and other folders (e.g. `Music`, `Pictures` & `Movies`) in which I do not use `--delete`. This is a *personal* choice that reflects how I manage/organize my data.

In the context of `rsync`, the `--delete` option simply means that deletions you make on your ***source*** folders are propagated to your ***destination*** folders.

#### Without the `--delete` option:

**1. In a *BACKUP* operation:**

###### i.   Source: `/MacHD_Folder/`

###### ii.  Destination: `/mountpoint/for/remote/storage`

```
rsync -rlAXtgoDiv --fake-super /MacHD_Folder/ /mountpoint/for/remote/storage
```

**2. In a *RESTORE* operation:**

###### i.   Source: `/mountpoint/for/remote/storage`

###### ii.  Destination: `/MacHD_Folder/`

```
rsync -rlAXtgoDiv --fake-super /mountpoint/for/remote/storage/ /MacHD_Folder
```

#### With the `--delete` option:

**1. In a *BACKUP* operation:**

###### i.   Source: `/MacHD_Folder/`

###### ii.  Destination: `/mountpoint/for/remote/storage`

```
rsync -rlAXtgoDiv --fake-super --delete --backup-dir=/mountpoint/for/remote/storage/deletes /MacHD_Folder/ /mountpoint/for/remote/storage
```

**2. In a *RESTORE* operation:**:

###### i.   Source: `/mountpoint/for/remote/storage`

###### ii.  Destination: `/MacHD_Folder/`

```
rsync -rlAXtgoDiv --fake-super /mountpoint/for/remote/storage/ /MacHD_Folder
```

Note the asymmetry between backup & restore operations when using the `--delete` option. This due to the fact that *nothing need be deleted* for the restore operation. Note also use of the `--backup-dir` option when using the `--delete` option: This causes `rsync` to *move* all deleted files & folders to the designated folder on the destination drive. You may think of this as a form of *"insurance"* for deleted files - it functions as the `Trash` folder does on your local MacHD.

#### Further Reading:

[This GitHub *recipe*](https://github.com/seamusdemora/seamusdemora.github.io/blob/master/RsyncWithNoMetaDataLoss.md) offers further explanations and useful options.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `rsync` version 3.0.6 as per Carbon Copy Cloner or 3.1.2 as per Homebrew, you can take a cue from Carbon Copy Cloner arguments:

`rsync -A -X -H -p --fileflags --force-change -l -N -rtx --protect-decmpfs --numeric-ids -go --delete-during --backup --backup-dir=</PATH/TO/STICK/BACKUP_when_using_delete> --protect-args <SRC>/ <DEST>`

Comment: `--protect-decmpfs` isn't available as of 3.1.3 anymore, see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/23415.

Answer (score 4):

I'd advise against pruning *meta-data* during a backup, particularly the *dot-files* e.g. `._$filename`, however if you really want to exclude the *dot-files* from your `rsync` command add `--exclude '.*'` to it.

```
rsync -av --exclude '.*' --progress --delete /Volumes/A/ /Volumes/B
```

Comment: This is good. I wasn't sure if removing *all* dot-files would be problematic (by the way, is there any difference between `'.*'` and `'/.*'`?). I don't think Finder copies all of them, may be just some associated. In that case I would prefer to exclude only those that are unnecessary (e.g., `.DS_Store`). And yes, those that might be important, but that I don't want to have in my log I can filter with regular expressions.

Comment: What the Finder copies is undocumented, and this is the source of everyone's problem when building a backup policy. You should maintain a copy of *all files* if you want a backup which could be used exactly in place of `A` disk.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Which is not the case, in case the main hard drive A dies, then I will buy a third hard drive C, copy from hard drive B to hard drive C and probably start using one of B or C. I say again, that this is not the kind of backup that one needs to use like what SuperDuper does. It's just that my photos are better in two places instead of just one.

Answer (score 3):

I have used rsync for backups at several jobs, and I use it at home.

I highly recommend it, but with some modifications. As a backup tool, it's great, but as an archiving tool it falls a little flat. Yes, it copies everything, but you don't get versions of everything, you always get the latest versions only.

I used this guide http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/ as a jumping-off point. Read the whole page. It does a great job of explaining the options, and outlines how you can implement incremental backups. And amazingly, the article is over 10 years old but is still applicable today. Gotta love unix.

Comment: Thanks. In any case I wanted to cover the special considerations that one might want to take under Mac OS X. I didn't really wanted just a guide of `rsync`. In any case, good link, it covers a lot of `rsync` but there is as of today a tool to do exactly that: `rsnapshot`.