# rsync : Show deleted files

Tags: macos, rsync

I'm in the process of porting scripts which use `rsync` to MacOS 10.15.7.

Typical commands in these scripts look like

```
rsync -rau --delete SOURCE DESTINATION
```

Is there a way to display, which files have been deleted from DESTINATION? On Linux, I would use the option `--info=del`, but on the Mac version of rsync, `--info` does not exist, as we can see [in the man-page](https://ss64.com/osx/rsync.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're intent on using the *ancient* Apple version of `rsync`, you might find the `--dry-run` option with the `-i` and `-v` (or `-vv`) options useful for listing the deletions.

```
rsync -rauivv --dry-run --delete SOURCE DESTINATION
```

If you want an affirmative record of what has been deleted, you could use the `--backup-dir=` option to actually save a copy of what's been deleted in a separate folder on the *DEST* (which could later be deleted).

```
rsync -rau --delete --backup-dir=/the/destination/backup SOURCE DESTINATION
```

Perhaps the easiest thing to do is avoid the **porting** process altogether by getting a current version of `rsync` via a 3rd party package manager: either [MacPorts (recommended)](https://www.macports.org/), or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

You might also find [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/444906/149366) worth a read.

Comment: +1 for the dry run option alone!

Answer (score 7):

The version of rsync supplied by Apple is very old (at least 17 years) it is version version 2.6.9 (which just happens to be the last rsync version released under GPL 2)

So the best fix for your issue is to install a modern version of rsync. It is available from all package mangers e.g. Macports, Homebrew.

Comment: AFAIK, Apple's version of `rsync` does include an option for backing up extended attributes.

Comment: Apple is avoiding GPL3 everywhere.  To my understanding that was also the reason to switch from bash to zsh.

Comment: From `man -M /usr/share/man rsync`: `-E, --extended-attributes   copy extended attributes, resource forks`, so Apple's version *does* support extended attributes and resource forks.

Comment: The issue is so old I have forgotten the details - but might be that vanilla rsync did not support extended attributes but Apple had forked it which I did not realise. There were other issues.